# How to update a YouTube video using YouTube Data API in Python

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Can someone tell me how do you update a YouTube video title using the YouTube Data API in Python.

I found the API's documentation not clear and couldn't understand, so I hit Stack Overflow.

Comment: start with the quick start https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to absorb and then tailor to your needs the official sample code provided by Google: [`update_video.py`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/update_video.py).

Note that this script is quite simple. But that may well be misleading, because the Python libraries used there hide away many API programming details involved when invoking YouTube API endpoints.

For example you have to be familiar with the so-called [OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization flows](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps) for to be able to *change* metadata associated to your YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0):

To update a video title in python with the YouTube Data api:

```
import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.videos().update(
        body={
          "id": "",
"snippet.title": "MyUpdatedTitle"
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When you run it in python it will ask you to chose the channel (if you have multiple channels) in the browser and then ask you to approve access.

Please note this is taking from the official developer docs which you can take a look at here:

```
[https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update][1]
```